# Detecting and dealing with outliers in a sales prediction dataset of "Rossmann"

Tags: regression, inference, data-transformation, outliers, boxplot

I have been working on a dataset for which the ***task is to forecast the sales of the drug sold by 1115 drug stores of the Rossmann chain.*** The dataset is fairly large with over ***1m records and as many as 9 variables of which "Sales" is one***. I began analyzing one of the variables named "Customers", demonstrating the "the number of customers on a given day", as per the description given in the dataset. I plotted the box plot of the variable in order to gain some insights of its spread and central tendency. Following is the graph that I thus begot;

[image]

From this plot, it is quite tempting to conclude that this variable is overwhelmed with many a outlier and is verily right skewed. However, refusing to make irresponsible inference, I now wish to answer a 2 fold question;

1. What ***definition of outlier fit the best for this variable and how to detect those?*** What ***factors must have influenced such spread of the dataset?*** I attach an image of first few records of the dataset so it subserves likely claims.

[image]

2. Having identified the outliers and having inferred their causes, how then must I deal with those? Now I particularly am interested in the following things:

   a. How must I deal with the outliers given the realm that I'm working on which is a ***sales prediction problem*** for a drug stores chain. I want to identify a ***domain specific and less profound solution.***

   b. (The fact that it's a ***"regression" problem*** must be kept in mind) What ***transformation*** suits the best?

---

I'm posting this answer in order to demonstrate further analysis on this question;

Heeding earlier advice of taking the logarithm of the "Customers" (IV) variable as well as the "Sales" (DV) variable, I begot the following graphs

1. Box plot of the "Customers" variable before and after the (log base 10) transformation

[image]

[image]

2. Box plot of the "Sales" variable before and after the (log base 10) transformation

[image]

[image]

3. Relationship (scatter plot) between "Customers" and the "Sales" variable earlier and after transformation (original vs original

[image]

[image]

Having added this information, I want to put a few more questions;

1. From predictions' point of view, ***did taking logarithm really help,*** for the ***relationship between the IV and the DV was already linear.***
2. From the inference point of view; ***what typical inference could a statistician make by comparing the respective box plots?***

*P. S. I have actually taken log10(values + 1) in lieu of log10(values) for a lot of records in both the variables were 0s.*

Comment: Your box plot would make more sense with a logarithmic scale. You probably need for that first to create a new variable which is log sales. That is a hint also for the kind of regression that may be best advised.

Comment: @NickCox ; First things first, I think there's a little confusion in here perhaps. You must be suggesting log transformation of the "customers" variable that the box plot demonstrates? Secondly, as far as my knowledge is concerned outliers better be observed from the actual (untransformed) distribution and that log transformation typically is used for ensuring "linearity" of the relationships which by far is not my concern. Thirdly, having suggested a log transformation of the variable, are you opining that a log transformation "generally" is a worthwhile way of portraying the outliers?

Comment: I am not surprised by marked skewness or outliers in sales data. Indeed; your graph shows log customers and that is what I meant in the first instance, but log sales would be worth looking at too. Sure, outliers that are high values show up more prominently on the original scale. The point of the logarithmic scale is to show them on a more appropriate scale for further analysis. But what is the goal here? If you want to identify outliers that are mistaken (e.g. someone entered the wrong value, whether honestly or not) then you may be better off on the original scale to start with.

Comment: @NickCox ; I want to know two things to begin with. One; I want to reason out the significant spread of the data from what popularly is known as the "Upper whisker" of the box plot. As far as I could see, only one point (that above the 7000 mark) could unquestionably be termed as an "outlier". Two; I want to predict the "sales" variable using linear regression (or other regression techniques that I would rather like you to suggest) while fulfilling the conditions on which regression is premised upon.

Comment: What is and what is not an outlier is just terminology. Outlier identification is not like identifying an elephant in a population of mice. The practical point to care about is whether the 7000 value is credible. If it is, then include it in the analysis. Predicting sales from the other variables may or may not work better with a transformation. My guess is that you would be better with a generalized linear model with a logarithmic link, but I can offer no guarantees based on just what you say.

Comment: I am with you on the first segment of your answer pertaining to outlier detection. On the transformation bit, let's say, for instance, that I put a few more variables in the dataset of (say) square root, cube root, and fourth root transformations alongside the one for log transformation. On what grounds then must I select the best amongst them? Having said that, one question that naturally comes to mind is, does "normality" of IVs or DV(s) matter for any form of regression? If not, then is it not true that extreme values are bound to affect the slope of the fitted line?

Comment: No answer here from me, just comments. Normality of predictors is irrelevant. After all, you have various 0, 1 predictor variables that can never be normal. It's conditional linearity you should be seeking.  That's it from me. You need to try an analysis and come back with any specific problem rather than wonder about what might happen.

Comment: @NickCox ; True, perhaps I'm wondering a bit too much. Thank you for helping me out :)

Comment: Why would a skewed distribution be a problem? E.g. you might speculate that customers is about proportional to sales. In that case, you can extrapolate quite well, unless you e.g. speculate that too croweded (or empty) a shop affects sales (e.g. negatively).

Comment: @Björn ; I'm convinced that it will not be a problem. In fact, as you could see from the scatter plots that I have shared, the relation between the "Customers" and the "Sales" variable is fairly linear, which I took in good stead. But out of curiosity, what if I take the log for both the variables in lieu of the original ones for prediction? What difference would it make if at all?

Comment: Linear scaling makes a lot of sense, because if on average each customers spend $\beta$, then $\text{sales} \approx \beta \text{customers}$. Taking logs of predictors & outcome impacts different methods/models you fit differently. E.g. something like xgboost does not care about monotone transformations of predictors, while in a linear model, you'd switch to $\log \text{sales}_i = \beta \log \text{customers}_i + \epsilon_i$, which means you think that $\text{sales}_i / \text{customers}_i^\beta = e^\epsilon_i$ (where the right hand side is close to 1, if variability is low).

Comment: @Björn Are you suggesting that even if a linear relationship between the IVs and DVs exist, a log transformation might still make sense?

Comment: I mean that it depends on what you believe about the data and some assumptions seem more natural than others. Was that not the question regarding when which transformation makes sense?

Comment: Yes, that's true. The subjectivity of the topic makes it quite riveting. I sure must dwell even further as I am already been doing. Thank you @Björn . Could you please also suggest a good book on this subject (covering transformations)